# SSRS SUM IIf from TODAY, WEEK, MONTH, YEAR

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to count how many incidents have been created `TODAY`, for the `WEEK`, `YEAR` and `TOTAL`.

I've been able to get the TOTAL using:

```
=Count(Fields!Issue_ID.Value, "My_Data_Set")
```

but I have not been successful getting the total COUNT for how many incidents have been created for: TODAY, WEEK, YEAR against `IncidentDateTime` field.

[image]

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvTo1.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jpas.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these expressions.

For today:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!IncidentDateTime.Value=Today.Date,1,0),"DataSetName")
```

For Year:

```
=SUM(IIF(YEAR(Fields!IncidentDateTime.Value)=Today.Year,1,0),"DataSetName")
```

For Week:

```
=SUM(IIF(DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Fields!IncidentDateTime.Value)=
DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Today),1,0),"DataSetName")
```

For Month:

```
=SUM(IIF(MONTH(Fields!IncidentDateTime.Value)=Today.Month,1,0),"DataSetName")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: How about for the month?

Comment: Everything works except for the MONTH. I'm getting #Error.